# Using Jquery in Node Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, global

I am trying to use JQuery in my Node Js Code but it is not working.
Please see my below Node JS code.

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(8080);
});
require("jsdom").env("", function (err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    $('#div1').append('<div>dd</div>');
});
```

My Index file is coming properly. There is a Div which has div1 Id in my Index.html but I couldn't append new div into my index.html.
What is the problem? Is there any problem in my code?

In addition, if I define `var $` in top of the code and move the `$('#div1').append('<div>dd</div>');` code out of the brackets such as

```
});

$('#div1').append('<div>dd</div>');
var db = require("./db_select");
```

Node JS throwing an error such as: `TypeError: $ is not a function`

How can I define a global $ ?

---

I've changed my code as below because I'm anticipating that it can be a sync problem.

```
var runHtml = function () {

    this.load = function () {
        var http = require('http'),
        fs = require('fs');

        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        console.log('Node Js is working');
            http.createServer(function (request, response) {
                response.writeHeader(200, {
                    "Content-Type": "text/html"
                });
                response.write(html);
                response.end();
            }).listen(8080);
        });
    };

    this.createjson = function () {
        require("jsdom").env("", function (err, window) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            var $ = require("jquery")(window);
            $('#div1').append('<div>dd</div>');
        });
    };

    if (this instanceof runHtml) {
        return this.runHtml;
    } else {
        return new runHtml();
    }
};

var runit = new runHtml();

runit.load().createjson();
```

However, when I run this code, I'm getting an error from the terminal such as: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createjson' of undefined`

Why am I getting this error?

As you can see I have a createjson function and I'm trying to call it after load function as using javascript chaning!

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery noconflict? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: You can achieve same things in a simpler way with [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: @legendofawesomeness I've looked at it just now and tried the implement but nothing changed. I anticipating there is a sync problem in my code because when I load my index page firstly I see a head section, then (1 sec later) I can see the body section. Therefore I think I have a sync problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are giving jsdom the actual index.html file you read.  The first argument to `.env()` needs to be your HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you please see my below question as well? I tried to use `require("jsdom").env("index.html", function (err, window) {` but nothing changed!

Comment: @Grcn - You are pretty far off in how to make this code work and I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing for you or try to reteach what the jsdom documentation already covers.  It appears that you haven't followed even the most basic tutorial for jsdom.  I'd suggest you start there to learn how it works and then move it into your specific code context.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I am pretty far off in how to make this code work and That's why I'm asking a question in here. I don't want to rewrite the whole things from you. I am very very new in Node JS and that's why I can ask stupid or simple questions. If you don't want to help me you don't have to answer me.  There Is No Need To Disrespect!!

Comment: No disrespect here - I'm attempting to help you here which is more than anyone else is doing.  I made a concrete suggestion that you follow a specific example in the jsdom documentation and when you get that working, then you figure out how to put in your own content.  Crawl, walk, run.  Don't just go directly to the more complicated coding situation when you are learning something new as you may have multiple things wrong and not know how to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Ok @jfriend00. Thanks for your explanations and suggestions. I didn't like the 'I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing' sentence but it is not important. Never Mind. Thanks again for you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal actually gave it away. When you get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createjson' of undefined` that tells you where to look. In your code, there is a thing, which has a property of `creaetejson`, that, at runtime, is `undefined`.

In your last code snippet, at the end, you have a line that goes `runit.load().createjson();`. This is a line that has a thing (the call to the load method) that has a property called `createjson`. Looking at the rest of that code snippet, we see that load is a method of `runit`, which is defined by the line above it `var runit = new runHtml();`. If we checkout the `runHTML` function, we find that it has a method called `load`. In this method, there is no return statement, so it returns `undefined` by default.

Returning to the line `runit.load().createjson();`, we can now see how it is evaluated: `runit` is a functional style class and `load` is a method on `runit`, which returns undefined. You called the `load` method on the `runit` class, which means that the line (aside from what it does in the `load` function) is the same as `undefined.createjson()`.

Now, in regards to solving the problem, there are a number of different ways to go. 
The simplest way may be to simply return the object from the load method. If you go that route, I suggest you [beef up your knowledge of the keyword this](https://codeburst.io/the-simple-rules-to-this-in-javascript-35d97f31bde3). You may also want to look into the keywords `async` and `await`.

Happy Coding